# How can I create an array that contains latitude and longitude and use for loop to mark the positions on google map in android

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fragment

I've just started coding in android and after a very long time I got my google map to work and have been able to put markers on it.

What I want to do next is create a array of latlng and use for loop to put a marker on the google maps. I cannot figure out how to do. Could someone please help me. I have done the following so far.

```
ArrayList<Markers> mMap = new ArrayList<Markers>();

public ArrayList arraylist[] = {new ArrayList(
                            new LatLng(30.243442, -1.432320)),
```

I would like to expand this later, hence I would like to use array list.

I understand how the for loop works, but I cannot work out how to implement it with this as I cannot get those locations from array to tag on my map.

```
      for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
        }
```

I am completely lost from this stage. Could someone please guide and help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you are wanting an array that stores the LatLng object. So, declare one like so:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locations;
```

And you also need to initialise your ArrayList:

```
locations = new ArrayList();
```

Now you can add locations to the array, using the ArrayList.add method:

```
locations.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```

Now that you have an ArrayList filled with some LatLng's, you can iterate over them using a foreach loop, like so:

```
for(LatLng location : locations){ 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
        .position(location)
        .title(...)
}
```

The above basically reads as:

For each location in the locations ArrayList, add a new marker, where the position of the marker is the location we're retrieving from out array

Tying it all together:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList();
locations.add(new LatLng(30.243442, -1.432320));
locations.add(new LatLng(... , ...));
.
.
.

for(LatLng location : locations){
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(location)
        .title(...)
}
```

Comment: hi, for some reason, the .add is underlined red. could you please explainn why?

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: I have no idea why. Does it offer a message when you hover over / click on it? Perhaps you are calling locations.add from the body of your class instead of from an inner method?

Comment: it says the following The method add(int, LatLng) in the type ArrayList<LatLng> is not applicable for the arguments (double, double)

Comment: If you declared your ArrayList like so: ArrayList<LatLng>. then you can only add a single LatLng for each entry in your ArrayList. In other words, the Type of Array is LatLng. Sounds like you're trying to pass in an integer as well as a LatLng (are you doing something like arrayList.add([some number], [someLatLng])? See my answer above - I'm only passing in one LatLng per Array entry. You should consider reading up on creating and using ArrayLists in Java.