# how to set firebase getChildren values in marker

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, google-maps-markers

In android I am getting `firebase` `response(latt,lngg)` by this code :

```
ref.child("USerCurrentLocation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        lattDonor = new double[size];
        lnggDonor = new double[size];
        int i = 0;
        Log.d("size1"," size = "+size);
        Log.d("latt",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" , "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Double latt = (Double) messageSnapshot.child("latt").getValue();
            Double lngg = (Double) messageSnapshot.child("lngg").getValue();
            Log.d("latt1", latt + " , " + lngg);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt,lngg)).title("Donor"));
            markers.add(marker);
            }
        }
```

Now I got this result in Log :

```
02-02 14:26:50.175 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt: USerCurrentLocation , {2233={lngg=45.34534234, latt=56.44332453}, 1234={lngg=67.0833, latt=46.45398745}, 410060215718654={lngg=67.0555454, latt=24.8731362}, 2341={lngg=67.0333, latt=24.9167}, 1345={lngg=53.09865348, latt=34.45739834}}
02-02 14:26:50.185 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt1: 46.45398745 , 67.0833
02-02 14:26:50.185 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt1: 34.45739834 , 53.09865348
02-02 14:26:50.185 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt1: 56.44332453 , 45.34534234
02-02 14:26:50.195 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt1: 24.9167 , 67.0333
02-02 14:26:50.195 4032-4032/com.example.haawztech.abdapplication D/latt1: 24.8731362 , 67.0555454
```

But when I set these values in marker I just got on marker which is last `latt` `lngg` in this `firebase` child.

How can I get all values marker in this project in this loop?

My `firebase` data set id

[image]

Comment: You are getting the lat and log correctly right

Comment: yes but i want to set all the latt lngs in marker ... .

Comment: I think there is no issue in fetching details from firebase as you are getting all latlong

Comment: But i am facing issue when i try to set marker on latt lngg all my values present just one marker which is last one in my database

Comment: Can you try to put this lat long in array and show markers from that array after fetching from firebase ? If then the issue persist then its the problem of showing marker

Comment: did you zoom in and look whether only one is showing ?;)

Comment: Yes, in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220690/how-can-i-create-an-array-that-contains-latitude-and-longitude-and-use-for-loop

Comment: By looking this your logic is correct check whether you are clearing your marker somewhere or you are writing map.clear();

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Marker array that will be used to hold all the markers. Initialize the array with variable 'size'

```
    Marker[] allMarkers = new Marker[size];
```

After that introduce a for..loop inside the DataSnapshot for..loop. Finally create the markers on the map using the array object created earlier. Below is a complete code of how you would implement it.

```
    ref.child("USerCurrentLocation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

    lattDonor = new double[size];
    lnggDonor = new double[size];
    int i = 0;
    Log.d("size1"," size = "+size);
    Log.d("latt",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" , "+dataSnapshot.getValue());

    Marker[] allMarkers = new Marker[size];


    for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {

        try {

        Double latt = (Double) messageSnapshot.child("latt").getValue();
        Double lngg = (Double) messageSnapshot.child("lngg").getValue();
        Log.d("latt1", latt + " , " + lngg);

        allMarkers[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt,lngg)).title("Donor"));

       // markers.add(marker);
        } catch(Exception ex){}
        }

    }
```